# Complex function plot using TikZ or PGFPlots

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I need to plot some steps of this approximation https://mathoverflow.net/a/27127 but don't know how to start.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you looked in the manual of either package? There are examples of how to plot functions, tables of data etc. Please be more specific on what exactly you have problems with. (note that complex functions are nothing but the x-axis as the real part of the function, and the y-axis as the complex part of the function, if this is one of the problems?)

Comment: That looks like it was created with the computer algebra system Sage using the [animate command](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/plotting/sage/plot/animate.html)

Comment: I don't need an animated version and I'm pretty familiar with TikZ and complex numbers, but at the moment I don't have any idea how to plot e.g. N = 3 case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed the exponent typo now it is behaving properly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[style=help lines] (-1.5,0) grid[step=1] (1.5,1.5);
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=0.5pt] (one) at (1,0) {};
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=0.5pt] (i) at (0,1) {};
\pgfmathsetmacro\myfactor{1cm/1pt} % Pff.. pt causes arithmetic overflow

\foreach \k in {1,...,100}{
\draw[opacity=1/\k] (1,0) let 
\p1=($(one)+([scale=pi/\k]i)$), 
\n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)/\myfactor},\n2 = {atan2(\y1,\x1)} 
in\foreach \l in {1,...,\k}{-- ($({\l*\n2}:{(\n1^\l)*1cm})$)};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like something I can start with, even if it doesn't compile. Thank you.

Comment: Line 17: ! Package tikz Error: + or - expected.

Comment: Updated to 3.0 and it works well. Thank you!

Comment: @GeMir My pleasure.